# azdo pipeline steps - how to use CreateStack cloud formation template output in further tasks

Tags: azure-devops, aws-cloudformation, azure-pipelines

I am using a Cloudformation template to create a secret in SecretsManager through AzDo pipelines, the CFT is very simple, it goes like this -

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "How to create secrets in Secrets Manager using an AWS CloudFormation template"
Parameters:
  SecretName: 
    Description: The name of the secret to be created
    Type: String
Resources:
  CreateCredentialsInSecretsManager:
    Type: 'AWS::SecretsManager::Secret'
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref SecretName
      Description: "This secret will be used in further steps."
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"dbuname": "datastoredb1"}'
        GenerateStringKey: "dbpwd"
        PasswordLength: 30
        ExcludeCharacters: '!"@/\:;'
Outputs:
  SecretNameVar:
    Value: !Ref SecretName
```

Now I want to use the "SecretNameVar" from "Outputs" section in the further tasks I have -

[image]

Properties defined on the SM task -
[image]
How can I use the output variables in the shell script or for that matter any other task?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use the output variables in the shell script or for that
>   matter any other task?

For this issue , you can use the form `$(<ReferenceName>.<VariableName>)` to refer to output variables in the downstream step. The referenceName is the name you set in Output variables section. For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks).

In addition ,we need to set `parameter isOutput=true` for the output variables.For example setting output variable with powershell script:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=varibaleName;isOutput=true;]value
```

Comment: Ha ha I figured it out yesterday night, but I was not using the reference as you've stated. For "Stack Outputs" drop-down in the "Options" section of the task if you select "Save stack outputs into task variables" would create the stack outputs as environment variables and can be accessed through the downstream steps. 

I am assuming if you are accessing the stack outputs within the same job, you do not need that reference, as $(<VarName>) worked just fine for me. But if you have multiple jobs and you wish to use the output from "job1.task" in "job2 or job3.task" your notation might help.